# Original Southeast Asian or Polynesian Literature (as Computer Readable Text) Online

Tags: reference-request

Wondering if there are any original documents in text format (i.e. "etexts") for any of the Southeast Asian or Polynesian mythology, folklore, or just general documents *written in their native language* (that are also copyright free or permissive like creative commons license or similar). Some of the languages that these could be in which I'm not sure is:

- Tagalog
- Telugu
- Tamil
- Malay
- Burmese
- Hawaiian
- Maori
- Japanese (I'm just including anyways).
- Thai
- Indonesian
- Javanese
- Rongorongo

Taking a look at something like [Tagalog literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tagalog_literary_works) brings me to a sort of Tagalog script such as [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20070512165449/http://www.gutenberg.org:80/files/14794/14794-8.txt), but it is a bit messed up and in romanized Tagalog rather than [Tagalog script](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/tagalog.htm). I am looking for the original scripts instead of romanized versions. [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/tl) doesn't have any in Tagalog script, for example, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Here are some [Tamil](http://www.projectmadurai.org/pmworks.html) ones. Here are some [Japanese](https://www.aozora.gr.jp). Both free and open source. All that's remaining is [Burmese](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/burmese.htm), [Thai](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/thai.htm), Indonesian, Hawaiian, Maori, and Tagalog. For Hawaii I found [this](http://ulukau.org/) but it is not open source (and I can't find the actual documents but it doesn't matter). Here is a [Thai epic](https://archive.org/details/anupongchaiwong_gmail_7/page/n21), but not in text format.

Comment: [Here](https://th.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%81) is some Thai stuff (wikisource), but I am having a hard time navigating, trying to find something like an Epic like [Thao Hung or Thao Chueang (ท้าวฮุ่งท้าวเจือง)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_literature).

Comment: You left out [Rongorongo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rongorongo)

Comment: Good point, no I don't read Japanese lol.